# Using Cramer's rule, solve the following.

Tags: determinant, systems-of-equations

$$x + y +  z  = 6$$
$$3x - y + 2z = 7$$
$$    3y -4z = -6$$

Tried everything. When I check my answer its incorrect, even when I check the example in my handbook I see its answer is wrong. Would like to see the correct method to solve this equation.

Comment: See my answer is that's what you're getting? If not post your solution here, We'll be more than happy to find out what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x + y + z = 6$$$$ 3x - y + 2z = 7$$ $$0x+ 3y -4z = -6$$

( I think you might have did something with $x$ in 3<sup>rd</sup> equation )

You should get
$$\Delta=19 , \Delta_1=19, \Delta_2=38, \Delta_3=57$$
$$\Rightarrow x=1 , y=2 , z=3$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. The mistake I made was incorrect signs.